# How to get X-Series labels in barplot?

Tags: r

```
> data(women)
> barplot(women$height,women$weight)
```

How can I get women weight as x label-axis?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 bp <- barplot(women$height,women$weight)
 axis(1, bp, women$weight)
```

[image]

Comment: Another option is to use "names.arg",
barplot(women$height,names.arg=women$weight)

Comment: Or more beautiful chart, barplot(women$height,names.arg=women$weight,main="Women Weight Vs Height", ylab="Height",xlab="Weight")